# How to set Facebook Access (from server) in JavasScript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

If I am using the server side flow to authenticate a user and acquire an access token, how can I set that access token in the JavaScript SDK and use it to make calls from the client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the user has finished the server side authentication flow the user is already authorized for your app, all you need to do is to use the [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) method:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
        console.log("authResponse: ", response.authResponse);
        FB.api("me", function(response2) {
            console.log("Hey there " + response2.name);
        });
    }
    else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
        // user is logged in to facebook but hasn't authorized your app, should not happen if he went through the server side authentication
    }
    else {
        // user is logged out of facebook, also should not happen
    }
}
```

As you can see you can simply use the js sdk to query the graph, there's no need to get the token manually, but in case you still need it, the `authResponse` should have the following format:

```
authResponse: {
    accessToken: "aaaaaaa",
    expiresIn: "bbbbbb",
    signedRequest: "cccccc",
    userID: "dddddd"
}
```

---

## Edit

If the user is logged into facebook and has allowed and interacted with your app then yes the `getLoginStatus` should return a valid access token.
There are a few cases in which this is not the case, one of them being that the token has expired.

As it states in the [Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/):

> **Desktop Web and Mobile Web apps which implement authentication with the Javascript SDK**
>
> Calling FB.getLoginStatus() or ensuring status: true is set when you
>   call FB.init() means that the next time a user lands on your
>   application and is signed into Facebook, the authResponse object you
>   are passed as a result of those calls will contain a fresh, valid
>   access token.
>
> In this case, its simply the act of the user using your application
>   which implicitly generates a new access token.

Comment: Thanks this is something I wasn't at all clear on. Just to make sure I understand. Once a user has authorized my app (whether this is done on the server or the client) then getLoginStatus will always return a valid authToken and a stratus "connected" and I won't need to have them reauthenticate?

Comment: This solution works fine, thanks. I had just one problem, response.status was returning null when I opened my page unlogged and, before refreshing it, logged in in another tab. To solve it I had to pass a second parameter to FB.getLoginStatus: "true", which forces the SDK to make a new request to Facebook and correctly update the login status. According to the following article, Facebook caches FB.getLoginStatus response. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/